# Android layout vs. custom view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I want to generate the following for my Android application.

[image]

I tried to achieve this using `RelativeLayout` and some drawables (empty circle, filled circle, dotted line) I created using XML , but I am not even close to it. Is it the right way to generate such views with layouts. If so, is `RelativeLayout` is the way to go? Or should I create a custom view for that?

Comment: Are this circles images or checkboxes?

Comment: @GokhanArik they are just images.

Comment: You should give more details. Is it only one image on left or will it change depending on spaces between textview?

Comment: @GokhanArik no, it is nut just one image. each circle should align with the center of the corresponding TextView on the right. as spaces between TextView s increases, the number of dots between circles should increase as well.

Comment: Try to use a ListView with custom Views

Comment: @NickF How to add dots between circles then?

Comment: use it as part of the image like circle with 2 small above and below

Answer (score 0):

why are there 4 dots between the last item and the one before it, while the other have 3 dots?

anyway, i think you can achieve those results by having a listView with custom items.

each item would be shown as a relativeLayout with 2 imageViews (one below the other) and a textView on the right of the upper one.

the upper imageView would have the large dot (filled or not), with optional dots above it, and the imageView below would stretch its size according to the textView (align to its bottom plus add some more for extra small-dots) and have tiled dots as its background.

another approach would be to have a listView of textViews and an imageView on its left, and you draw the circles according to what the listView is currently showing (even while scrolling). it's much harder, but might be more precise.